# Ubuntu Run Python file from virtual environment without activation

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv

As you all know; in windows, we can run a python file from a virtual environment without activating the virtual environment like bottom;

```
# that is windows environment, we can run python files from cmd like that;
.\env\scripts\python.exe my_py_file.py
```

Is it possible to do it in WSL - Ubuntu operating system ?

Answer (score 1):

On *Nix you can use the following path: `./env/bin/python`.

Comment: that is not involving the packages from virtual environment. Says "..." module not found.

Comment: Are you sure, that you have installed the package for the virtual environment?

Comment: yeah I have installed tkinter but it is not applied to that.